# Use ASP .NET MVC Identity application to authenticate users in external API (PostgreSQL)

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, identity, authorize

I have an application without any authorization, working with PostgreSQL database.
I have created a new solution with ASP .NET Web Application, chose "use individual user accounts" and managed it to work with another PostgreSQL database (which stores only the AspNet Tables).

What I want to do:
I want to authorize actions in my Api by forcing user to login in the asp web app. For example when I invoke controller action that requires authorization, I want to be redirected to login page in the asp app and after logging I want to be back in my main application with all the grants.
Looks like I want to create something like this:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services

[image]

But still I feel like there is nothing well explained in the tutorial. I don't get what to put in the server application and what to put in my Api...

Comment: Can you please post your some code here?

Comment: but what code? I did make an application from the VS template, installed Npgsql and Npgsql for EF, changed web config, made IdentityDBContext for Npgsql, created db with identity tables. In the main application I don't have anything that connects both of the applications.

Comment: @DiSaSteR the question is a bit confusing. Do you have *one* web application or many? If many, why? Do you really want to deploy them to different virtual directories or servers? If not, why not a *single* web application with class projects?

Comment: I have one working web application. Now I want it to authorize any action by logging to another application, which will be deployed on IIS. Works like logging with facebook to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand the question but if I do, this might help you.

You may want to implement your own authorization server (just an app with endpoints), which holds all the Identity but no business logic.

There are 2 ways of doing this. You either have a login screen on your main app which sends the credentials over to your auth server which then returns the token or whenever a user requests the data from your main app and such data isn't public, you redirect to the auth server which logs the user in... something like 3rd party login with twitter, google etc. openid stuff.

Here are the link that might be what you're looking for:

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/

Hope this helps

EDIT:

Again, maybe I'm not understanding the question. Here is another link that might help someone looking for what I described above. The link points to an article of a series of articles on WebAPI, JWT token, Authorization, Angular and all that good stuff. I highly recommend the guy's blog if you into this stuff...

http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/

Comment: I am still nowhere, what I can find is always about the single application, nothing about the AspNet tables with users, roles etc :/

Comment: IdentityServer is a standalone application that can be used to only issue tokens (authenticate/authorize users) for your main application (data transmitted over http). If this is not what you are looking for I suggest you rephrase your question, explain a liitle bit cleare what it is you are looking for...